# Возврат данных от createAsycnThunk(TypeScript) в зависимости от полученных данных от сервера

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, mongodb, redux-thunk

1. Есть createAsyncThunk на TypeScript, который отправит на сервер логин и пароль для регистрации:

   ```
     export interface NewUserInterface {
     username: string,
     password: string,
     _id: string,
     createdAt: string,
     updatedAt: string
    }

   export interface NewUserDataInterface {
   token: string,
   newUser: NewUserInterface,
   message: string
   }
    export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk<NewUserDataInterface, {username:string, password:string}, {rejectValue:string}>(
            'auth/registerUser', 
            async function ({username, password}, {rejectWithValue}) {
                try {
                    const response = await instance.post('/register', {
                        username,
                        password
                    })
                    if(response.data.token){
                        window.localStorage.setItem('token', 
        response.data.token)
                }

                return response.data;
            } catch (error) {
                return rejectWithValue('')
            }
        }
    )
   ```
2. На сервере контроллер обработает запрос, и дальше по логике если такого юзера нет, зарегистрирует нового, если же юзер такой существует то вернет сообщение, что "такой юзер уже есть". На фронте, я в любом случае получу положительный статус и нового юзера или сообщение от сервера. Но в createAsyncThunk я указал, что верну interface который ему передал NewUserDataInterface, по этому при создании юзера все работает, но при регистрации с уже существующим логином все крашится ибо  interface который возвращает thunk не такой конструкции как если с сервера приходит одно сообщение.
   Контроллер:

   ```
        export const register = async function (request, response) {
            try {
                const { username, password } = request.body;
                const isUser = await User.findOne({username});
                if(isUser){
                    return response.json({message: 'such user is already exist'})
                }
                const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
                const newUser = new User({
                    username: username,
                    password: hashPassword
                });
                const token = jwt.sign({id: newUser._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: '30d'})
                await newUser.save();
                response.json({
                    newUser,
                    token,
                    message: 'user heas been created'
                })

            } catch(error){
                response.json({message: 'error creating user'})
            }
        }
   ```
3. В extrareducers ругается если сервер вернет сообщение, а не полноценного пользователя ибо не знает куда записать action.payload.newUser.username ибо thunk вернул только сообщение

   ```
                .addCase(registerUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                    state.username = action.payload.newUser.username;
                    state.token = action.payload.token;
                    state.status = action.payload.message;
                })
   ```

Вопрос, можно ли передать в thunk, передать 2 интерфейса и в зависимости от ответа сервера использовать один из них. Или в таких случаях другой подходи используют?